# Find Length of Line in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, math, graphics, line

I want to find a length of line. I have initialize a coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2 using mouse Events. When i try to find distance as shown below:

```
public class LineFunctions {
    static int dpi;
    static double pixel_per_cm;
    public LineFunctions(){
        Toolkit tk;
        tk=Main.frame.getToolkit();
        dpi=tk.getScreenResolution();
        pixel_per_cm=dpi/2.54;
    }
    public double lengthInPixel(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
        double length_in_pixel;
        double x=Math.pow((x2-x1), 2);
        double y=Math.pow((y2-y1), 2);
        length_in_pixel = Math.sqrt(x+y);
        return length_in_pixel;
    }
    public double lengthInCm(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){

        double length_in_pixel=lengthInPixel(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        double length_in_cm = length_in_pixel / pixel_per_cm;
        System.out.println("Length in Cm= "+length_in_cm);
        return length_in_cm;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        frame=new JFrame("LINE FRAME");
    }
    static class ImageComponent extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
        Line2D line;
            int x1,y1,x2,y2;
            public ImageComponent() {
                addMouseListener(this);
                addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                  super.paintComponent(g);
                  Graphics2D gd=(Graphics2D)g;
                  line=new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                  gd.draw(line);
            }
            @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        x1=e.getX();
                    y1=e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    x2=e.getX();
                    y2=e.getY();
                    LineFunctions lf=new LineFunctions();
                    double length=lf.lengthInCm(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                    System.out.println("Line Length="+length);
                    repaint();                    
    }
    .......................
    ........................
}
```

This code finds the length of line from the coordinates, but when i find the length of a line drawn on my screen from the **RULER** it doesn't saw me the same length as i got from the above code. So, What is the Problem with this and how can i find the exact length of line?

Comment: Do you have any specs for your monitor? Are you sure the screen resolution, as reported by the toolkit, is correct?

Comment: I think its correct... but not sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`getNormalizingTransform()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getNormalizingTransform%28%29) of the `GraphicsConfiguration` of your `GraphicsDevice` to determine the required geometry. In particular, an *identity* transform indicates that "72 units in user space equals 1 inch in device space."

Also consider [`Math.hypot()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29) for more accuracy.