# Find the length of line in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to find the length of a line i have drawn inside a canvas. I already can draw the line inside the canvas but badly need to find its length.

Find this link, but i want to know what are the things needed to have a precise measurement. Thanks.

[Link i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442389/find-length-of-line-in-java)

So far this is my code:

```
$("#myCanvas").bind('mousemove', function(e){   
                    var totalOffsetX = 0;
                    var totalOffsetY = 0;       
                    var currentElement = this;

                    do{
                        totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
                        totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
                    }
                    while(currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

                    endX= e.pageX - totalOffsetX;
                    endY = e.pageY - totalOffsetY;

                    drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                });             
            }).mouseup(function(data){
                if(trigger = "1"){
                    $('.draggable').draggable( "disable" );
                }else{
                    $('.draggable').draggable("enable");
                }   
                $(this).unbind('mousemove');
            });
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6):

Since ECMA-262, there's a [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) method, which *returns the square root of the sum of squares of its arguments*.

```
Math.hypot(v1, v2) === Math.sqrt(v1*v1 + v2*v2)
```

You could create a simple helper function:

```
function lineDistance(p1, p2) {
  return Math.hypot(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may this formula to calculate the distance between two points with startX,startY,endX,endY.

```
function lineDistance( point1, point2 ){
    var xs = 0;
    var ys = 0;

    xs = point2.x - point1.x;
    xs = xs * xs;

    ys = point2.y - point1.y;
    ys = ys * ys;

    return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}
```

Comment: How will i know if its in mm, cmm, or inches or pixel?

Comment: @user3651476 The length computed above is always in pixels.

Comment: BTW, what is the use of DPI in conversting pixels to cm? TIA

Comment: @user3651476 DPI refert to Dot Per Inch. (Pixel length / DPI) = (physical length in inch), then convert to cm. And here is an online calculator [https://www.sven.de/dpi/](https://www.sven.de/dpi/)

Answer (score 1):

use distance formula distance as distance= √((x2– x1)2+ (y2– y1)2)

i.e in JS

```
distance: function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  let dx = x2 - x1;
  let dy = y2 - y1;

  dx = dx * dx;
  dy = dy * dy;

  return Math.sqrt( dx + dy );
},
```